# iCal to RSS - PHP Conversion

Tags: php

Im looking for a way to convert a iCal file to an RSS feed, anyone know of anything existing that could help me achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of this [iCalender parser PHP class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3278-PHP-Parse-and-extract-event-information-from-iCalendar.html) to extract data as you need and then format the extracted data in to a `feed`.